# WPF How can i change ContentControl content

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i change content control's content when button is clicked. For example i have content control with user control named "Home Page" when i clicked at some button i wanna change content control' content with another user control.

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:PAL_PlayAndLearn.ViewModels"
    xmlns:Pages="clr-namespace:PAL_PlayAndLearn.Pages"
    ...>
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:AppViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       <ContentControl Content="{Binding HomePage}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Can you help me, because i don't have many time.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code, to answer this properly we need to see your main view model, the binding that maps it to the content control and the name of the other content control you want to display.

Answer (score 6):

You basically need one main, or parent view model. This view model should have a property of type `BaseViewModel` in it, let's say named `ViewModel`. *All* of your other page view models should extend this base `class`.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

Now, because your view models all have a base type of `BaseViewModel`, they can *all* be set as the value for the `ViewModel` property... so to load a new view model, you set it as the value for this property:

```
ViewModel = new HomeView();
```

But how do we display the related views? Let's use `DataTemplate`s to do that for us... add this and a similar entry for every view model that you will be using here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HomeViewModel}">
    <Views:HomeView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now WPF will render our views whenever we set the relating view model as the value for the `ViewModel` property. So finally, the `Button`? Well for that we need an `ICommand` in the main view model that is hooked to a `Button` in the main view and I recommend using the [`RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030). Note that you'll need to alter your main view:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Add your Buttons or Menu here, above where the views will be -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding HomePage}"/>
</Grid>
```

So, when a `Button` is clicked in the main view, you simply change the value of the `ViewModel` property and the `DataTemplate` will ensure that the relevant view is rendered in the UI. This is one of my own custom `ICommand` implementations like the `RelayCommand` that would load the view model if it wasn't already loaded:

```
public ICommand DisplayHomeView
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => ViewModel = new HomeViewModel(), 
        canExecute => !IsViewModelOfType<HomeViewModel>()); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sheridan answer is excellent but I give a full solution because I loose some time to put everything together. Hope it could help someone :-) ....

Please note than local:UserControlSpecialSignalTtrModel inherits from SignalProviderSpecial.

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParametricStudyAnalysis.ScopeSelection.Special"
             xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid" x:Class="ParametricStudyAnalysis.ScopeSelection.Special.UserControlAddSpecialSignal"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UserControlAddSpecialSignalModel></local:UserControlAddSpecialSignalModel>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControlSpecialSignalTtrModel}">
            <local:UserControlSpecialSignalTtr/>
        </DataTemplate>     
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <GroupBox Header="Signal type" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl Name="DataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialSignalEntries}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SpecialSignalEntrySelected}" Height="200">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" Title="Type of special signal" ReadOnly="True"></xcdg:Column>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Parameters" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,3,0,0" Padding="5">
            <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" 
                            DataContext="{Binding SpecialSignalEntrySelected, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            Content="{Binding SignalProviderSpecial}">
            </ContentControl>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```